# Unable to wget virtualhost from instance itself

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, wkhtmltopdf

I have LAMP setup on Ec2 instance and setup a virtual hosts e.g

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerName xx.xx.xx.xx
    ServerAdmin test@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dir1

..
..
</VirtualHost>
```

I am able to access the vhost contents publicly. But when I ssh to instance and 
try: wget xx.xx.xx.xx (public ip), that does not seems to resolve. I need a way to resolve it locally to generate pdf using `wkhtmltopdf` .

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if you can, but have you tried putting your server name in /etc/hosts so that it can resolve from the local machine? You would want to map the domain name of your server to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EC2 intances aren't accessible by their own public IP addresses from within the instance itself.

The Internet Gateway does static 1:1 network address translation between your assigned public IP and the private IP that's actually bound to your stack.  Accessing your instance using its public IP would require a hairpin connection through the Internet Gateway, which isn't supported.

You can use the `ec2metadata` command with the `--local-ipv4` option to get your instance's IP address, and include it right in the command line:

```
$ wget http://$(ec2metadata --local-ipv4)/path/goes/here
```

---

Alternately, and slightly more advanced... you can change the way your DNS is configured, as long as your hostname isn't at the zone apex (e.g., this works for `api.example.com` or `www.example.com` but not the bare domain `example.com`).

If you configure the DNS to use a CNAME record, something like this...

```
www CNAME ec2-54-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
```

...where the ec2-... is the EC2-assigned hostname of your public IP (you can find this with `ec2metadata --public-hostname` or in the console, where it's called "public DNS").

If you configure DNS this way, and you have [enabled DNS hostnames in your VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html), then your hostname will resolve to your *external* IP address if queried from *outside* your VPC, but will resolve to your *internal* IP address if queried from *inside* your VPC.  (This also works with EC2 Classic).

With this configuration, you can access your instance internally, using the hostname, but outside lookups continue to work, as well.

To illustrate this for those who may not be familar with this functionality:

Querying from inside the VPC, it resolves to the private address:

```
$ dig ec2-54-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-54-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 172.31.yyy.yyy
```

Querying from outside the VPC, using Google's public DNS server:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 ec2-54-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-54-xxx-xxxx-xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com. 21599 IN A 54.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

If your public hostname is a CNAME pointing to the "ec2-..." hostname, this internal resolution will follow.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, I got around this by entering public IP to inbound list for http/https in assigned security group.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll have to test that behavior again.  The problem you might have with that is, according to the pricing tables, you will be paying for that traffic to "leave" your network and come back again, $0.01/GB each direction, because you are using the public IP address.

Comment: I know that was poor guess :)